# Dialogflow : Provide Response after delay

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a requirement to trigger an event from webhook which calls follow-up intent after 20 seconds delay.

I am trying to trigger custom event from setTimeOut within promise so that it calls desired intent.

```
function payment(agent){
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
      return delay(5000).then(() => {console.log('Hello');
                             agent.setFollowupEvent('payment_completed');
                                    });
  }
```

console.log gets executed but event is not triggered.Please help.

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet what ever you have done so far as an example